# A 10mm long creature in the California dust

Tags: species-identification

[image]
I observed this tiny creature burrowing through the dusty soil of Cachuma Lake Recreation Area in Santa Barbara County, California, on June 8, 2014, about 7 a.m. I have really no clue what it could be, other than an annelid, or newly hatched type of legless lizard or snake. But it seems too tiny for the latter. Yet, I would think an annelid would need more moisture, or different soil. Do worms live in dust? I watched it for about five minutes, maybe more. Burrowing under and re-emerging. So that seemed to be its normal environment.

Here's a closeup, and a link to a Youtube page I put up for it. [Video on Youtube of animal's movement](https://youtu.be/uVU-ycKEdxo)

[image]

Comment: The creatures movement (youtube) is NOT that of an annalid. They contract and expand rather than zigzagging like this creature does. Zigzagging is a snakelike movement. Unfortunately, I am by no means an expert an Californian fauna.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't put my finger on it, but yes, that's it - it doesn't move like a worm, which is why I'm very curious what this is. Thanks for helping clarify that in my mind.

Comment: could it be an enchytraeidae?

Comment: @Jordi_Zambrino Aren't all *enchytraeidae* aquatic?

Comment: Just found [here](http://www.popsci.com/scitech/article/2008-08/worlds-smallest-snake) that the worlds smallest snake is still four inches. That makes a snake very unlikely. Hmm confused now.

Comment: http://www.agpix.com/view_caption.php?image_id=590425

Comment: @Jordi Sorry, still getting used to how this site works. Spent too long editing ...  What I meant to say was: Thanks for the reference to _enchytraeidae_. At least per the Wikipedia page, there are some terrestrial species, known as potworms.  And, I have to say, the creature in the image on [this page](http://www.agpix.com/view_caption.php?image_id=590425) looks pretty similar. But ... they tend to live in much wetter environments. This was dry and dusty, and it looked very much at home. You can also find videos of potworms in compost bins, and they move similarly to this.

Comment: Also, I did run this by a curator of reptiles, who also said it was not a snake (I thought it might be a juvenile Brahminy Blind Snake, an invasive species). He thought it might be a beetle larva but, while I'm not a professional entomologist, I've seen and handled a fair number of larvae, and this just doesn't scream "grub" to me.

Comment: Well, maybe I stand corrected: BugGuide.net has a [similar picture](http://bugguide.net/node/view/1029466/bgpage) of a Stiletto Fly larva found in Santa Barbara County. And [The Clueless Gardener blog](http://thecluelessgardeners.blogspot.com/2008/03/potworms-enchytraeidae.html) has some comments on behavior - says they're very strong, and move very fast.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer this question and close it. Based on the location, the environment, its appearance and behavior, I'm 90% sure that this creature was a Stiletto Fly (Therevid) larva. Most likely an Acrosathe sp., as those tend to be very common in the area. Thanks to all for your help in clarifying and narrowing it down for me.

Comment: You are probably right. Unless you can find an expert on Californian flies, it's unlikely you will ever be 100% sure.